# How to place a control at arbitrary location in a Grid layout panel?

Tags: wpf, windows-8

Is it possible to place a control at arbitrary location in a Grid layout panel?

Or should I use the Canvas layout panel?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the rows and columns functionality of the `Grid` then just use a `Canvas`, otherwise you can use `LayoutTransform`, `RenderTransform` or the `Margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use Canvas and randomize the control's Left and Top properties.

Comment: Is it possible to use Grid instead of Grid?